# Get the location of all company's branches on a map

Tags: android, api, google-maps

Can i get the location of the all the company's branches form the map by entering just name of company so that i can use it in my application i.e.
if i enter "Levi's" it should return the branches locations in a city .

Comment: you can google such a question, this has no code and you're looking for an opinion...try rewriting it

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to google places to get lat,lng of the location and then show it on the map by setting markers. 
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Small portion of the code you should use (there's a better example in the link above)

```
Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                    String addressString = place.getAddress().toString();
                    List<android.location.Address> addresses;
                    actionBar.setTitle(addressString);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 1);
                        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude(), addresses.get(0).getLongitude());
                            markerOptions.position(latLng);
                            markerOptions.title("Searched location");
                            mMap.clear();
                            markerLatLng = latLng;
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        }
                        }catch(IOException e){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem finding your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do but I think the auto complete option might be the best for you.